# How to implement a thread-safe SQLite db in Qt

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I have a single db (STOCKLIST.db), and I want to access the db through multiple threads.

Each thread will run a analysis but this is not the point I want to ask.

This is my preliminary code, since I'm not familiar with the multi-thread process with SQL.

I already **turn on the WAL mode**, ****add a mutex**** and **give each connection its own connection to the database** why I still get these error.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

**.h**

```
class testRunable : public QRunnable {
    public:
        void run() override;
    private:
        //QSqlDatabase db_;
        QMutex mutex_;
};
```

**.cpp**

```
void testRunable::run() {
    //each thread needs its own connection to the database
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("STOCKLIST.db");

    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "DB Connected.";
    }
    
    QSqlQuery sLIST(db);
    mutex_.lock(); // acquire the mutex
    sLIST.exec("SELECT * FROM mystocks");
    while (sLIST.next()) {
        QString symbol = sLIST.value("symbol").toString();
        QString name = sLIST.value("name").toString();
        qDebug() << symbol << name << " thread ID: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
        // (TODO) strategy will be here to scan all stocks
        // results(order) will be saved to another table 
    }
    db.close();
    mutex_.unlock();
}
```

**main file**

```
// set SQLite to WAL mode
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("STOCKLIST.db");

if (!db.open()) {
    qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
}
else {
    qDebug() << "DB Connected.";
}

QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
if (query.next()) {
    QString mode = query.value(0).toString();
    qDebug() << "Current SQLite mode is:" << mode;
}
db.close();

// multi-thread
QThreadPool threadPool;
threadPool.setMaxThreadCount(4);

// Submit the query task to the thread pool
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    testRunable* query = new testRunable();
    threadPool.start(query);
}
```

Comment: As written in the documentation - create and open the QSqlDatabase in the thread you want to use it.

Comment: @chehrlic I do create aand open db in the thread, right?

Comment: No - you're re-using the existing connection / re-add it with the same (default) connection name.

Comment: @chehrlic I see, I have to specify the second argument in "addDatabase" method. But do you have any suggestions on giving each thread a different name? Thanks!

Comment: Use a global number, the thread id or whatever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to synchronously access SQLite query with multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76132462/how-to-synchronously-access-sqlite-query-with-multiple-threads)

Comment: @Atmo Hi Expert, I'm still figuring out the issue and studying your suggestion. I've updated my question. It will be helpful if you can give some hints. :))