# How to synchronously access SQLite query with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite, qt

I have a stock list in the main process, and I created 4 threads trying to pass each row of it to the multiple threads.

According to the result, it seems like threads are not synchronized, and duplicate connection exist.

But I've already use mutex lock, and also use factory pattern to avoid duplicate connection name.

I have no clue about what's going on.

Thanks a lot!

[image]
**main.cpp**

```
QThreadPool threadPool;
threadPool.setMaxThreadCount(4);

QMutex mutex;

while (stockListQuery.next()) {
    QString name_ = stockListQuery.value("name").toString();

    mutex.lock();
    testRunable* query = new testRunable(db, name_);
    threadPool.start(query);
    mutex.unlock();
}
threadPool.waitForDone();
```

**.h**

```
class testRunable : public QRunnable {
public:
    testRunable(QSqlDatabase db, const QString &name);
    void run() override;

private:
    QSqlDatabase db_;
    QMutex m_mutex;
    QString name_;
};
```

**.cc**

```
testRunable::testRunable(QSqlDatabase db, const QString &name): db_(db), name_(name)
{
}

void testRunable::run() {

    QString ids = QString::number((int)QThread::currentThread());
    QSqlDatabase db = DBFactory(ids).getDatabase();
    int iterations = 0;

    while (1) {
        m_mutex.lock();
        qDebug() << name_ << " " << db.connectionName();
        m_mutex.unlock();

        if (iterations >= 1) {
            break; // stop the loop and exit the thread
        }

        iterations++;

        QThread::sleep(1); // seconds
    }

}
```

**Update** Thanks for @user4581301, I revised my usage of mutex below, and one of my questions is resolved. Oh God.

You can see there's no duplicated stock on the console.
But the other issue about duplicate connection name still exists.

I guess this is relating to my factory pattern. I saved all of the connections in a map to avoid duplicated connection, and I'm still figuring out.

Thanks for all of you.

[image]

**main.cpp**

```
    QThreadPool threadPool;
    threadPool.setMaxThreadCount(4);

    QMutex mutex;

    // Submit the query task to the thread pool
    while (stockListQuery.next()) {
        QString name_ = stockListQuery.value("name").toString();

        testRunable* query = new testRunable(db, name_, mutex); <--- ref of mutex should be passed in the function
        threadPool.start(query);
    }
    threadPool.waitForDone();
```

To @Mooing Duck, what do you mean putting multiple things into stockListQuery with the same name?

**.h**

```
class DBFactory {
public:
    QSqlDatabase getDatabase();
    void setConnetName(const QString& connectName);
private:
    QString conName_;
    QMap<QString, QSqlDatabase> m_;
};


class testRunable : public QRunnable {
public:
    testRunable(QSqlDatabase db, const QString &name, QMutex& mutex);
    void run() override;

private:
    DBFactory dbFac_;
    QSqlDatabase db_;
    QMutex& m_mutex;
    QString name_;
};
```

**.cpp**

```
QSqlDatabase DBFactory::getDatabase()
{
    if (m_.contains(conName_)) {
        return m_[conName_];
    }

    // Create a new database connection object
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", conName_);
    db.setDatabaseName("STOCKLIST.db");

    if (!db.isOpen()) {
        db.open();
    }

    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.exec("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
    if (query.next()) {
        QString mode = query.value(0).toString();
        //qDebug() << "Current SQLite mode is:" << mode;
    }

    // save to map
    m_[conName_] = db;
    

    return db;
}

void DBFactory::setConnetName(const QString& connectName)
{
    conName_ = connectName;
}


testRunable::testRunable(QSqlDatabase db, const QString &name, QMutex& mutex): db_(db), name_(name), m_mutex(mutex) {
}

void testRunable::run() {

    
    QString ids = QString::number((int)QThread::currentThread());
    dbFac_.setConnetName(ids);
    QSqlDatabase db = dbFac_.getDatabase();

    m_mutex.lock();
    qDebug() << name_ << " " << db.connectionName();
    stockCrawler(name_);
    saveToTable("result_table", db);
    m_mutex.unlock();

}
```

**Update2**

I simplified and did some refactoring, and this is the status:

1. Connections for four threads are created, and set to WAL mode.
2. "database is locked Unable to fetch row" I'm not sure what's this error message.
3. Thanks for Atmo's guidance, I'm still googling for the error messages and studying your suggestion.

[image]

**main.cpp**

```
...
    QSharedPointer<sqliteConnectionFactory> factory(new sqliteConnectionFactory("STOCKLIST.db"));
    QThreadPool threadPool;
    threadPool.setMaxThreadCount(4);

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Submit the query task to the thread pool
    while (stockListQuery.next()) {
        QString name = stockListQuery.value("name").toString();
        QString symbol = stockListQuery.value("symbol").toString();

        testRunable* query = new testRunable(name, symbol, factory);
        threadPool.start(query);
    }
    threadPool.waitForDone();
```

**.h**

```
class sqliteConnectionFactory {
public:
    sqliteConnectionFactory(const QString &dbName);
    QSqlDatabase createConnection();
private:
    QString dbName_;
    static QMap<QString, QSqlDatabase> connMap_;
};


class testRunable : public QRunnable {
public:
    testRunable(const QString& name, const QString& symbol, const QSharedPointer<sqliteConnectionFactory>& factory);
    void run() override;

private:
    static QMutex mutex_;
    QString name_;
    QString symbol_;
    QSharedPointer<sqliteConnectionFactory> factory_;
};
```

**.cpp**

```
sqliteConnectionFactory::sqliteConnectionFactory(const QString& dbName): dbName_(dbName)
{
}

QSqlDatabase sqliteConnectionFactory::createConnection()
{
    QString connectname = QString::number((int)(QThread::currentThread()));

    if (!connMap_.contains(connectname)) {
        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", connectname);
        db.setDatabaseName(dbName_);

        if (!db.open()) {
            qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
            assert(0);
        }

        QSqlQuery setting(db);
        setting.exec("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
        if (setting.next()) {
            QString mode = setting.value(0).toString();
            qDebug() << "Create a new connection: " << connectname;
            qDebug() << "Current SQLite mode is: " << mode;
        }
        connMap_.insert(connectname, db);
    }
    return connMap_.value(connectname);

}

QMap<QString, QSqlDatabase> sqliteConnectionFactory::connMap_;

QMutex testRunable::mutex_;

testRunable::testRunable(const QString &name, const QString &symbol, const QSharedPointer<sqliteConnectionFactory>& factory): name_(name), symbol_(symbol), factory_(factory) {
    
}

void testRunable::run() {

QSqlDatabase db = factory_->createConnection();

top_crawler* stockCrawler_ = new top_crawler();
stockCrawler_->InitCrawler(symbol_.toStdString());
std::vector<Spot> spots_ = stockCrawler_->GetSpots();
std::vector<double> ma5_ = stockCrawler_->GetMA5();
std::vector<double> ma10_ = stockCrawler_->GetMA10();
std::vector<QDateTime> series_ = stockCrawler_->GetDateTime();
std::vector<double> close_ = stockCrawler_->GetClosef();
auto latestDayPrice = stockCrawler_->GetLatestClosePrice();

int status = -1;
int cross = 0;
CrossList CL;

QSqlQuery query3(db);
for (int i = 0; i < close_.size(); ++i) {

        QVector<QString> queryBuffer;
        if (ma5_[i] >= ma10_[i] && status != 1) {
            if (status == 0) {
                cross++;
                CL.addSpot(close_[i], series_[i], i);
                queryBuffer.push_back(symbol_);
                queryBuffer.push_back(series_[i].toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                queryBuffer.push_back(QString::number(close_[i]));
            }
            status = 1;
        }
        else if (ma5_[i] < ma10_[i] && status != 0) {
            if (status == 1) {
                cross++;
                CL.addSpot(close_[i], series_[i], i);
                queryBuffer.push_back(symbol_);
                queryBuffer.push_back(series_[i].toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                queryBuffer.push_back(QString::number(close_[i]));
            }
            status = 0;
        }
        else {
            // error
        }
        if (!queryBuffer.empty()) {
            QMutexLocker locker(&mutex_);
            query3.prepare("INSERT INTO cross_point (stock_id, date, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                query3.bindValue(i, queryBuffer[i]);
            }
            if (!query3.exec()) {
                qWarning() << "Failed to insert data into table";
                qWarning() << query3.lastError().text();
            }
        }
    }

    
    qWarning() << "cross:" << cross;
    CL.printList();
}
```

Comment: Should be no need for the mutex locks in the first block unless `QThreadPool`'s `start` method is a lot stupider than I think it should be.

Comment: In the second block, each job has its own mutex. That's where your bug will probably be. Nothing can prevent each `testRunable` from acquiring their own mutex and hitting the database all at the same time. They need to share a single mutex.

Comment: I don't know about Qt. On the lower level, SQLite supports multithread out of the box **provided that each thread has its own connection**. If you share a single connection between threads, it will work also provided you lock a **shared** mutex for each and every access to the database.

Comment: @user4581301To share a single mutex, seems like I need to declare a mutex in main file, and maybe pass it by ref as an argument of testRunnable, right?

Comment: @prapin No, I created different connections for different threads, I gave them different connection name. You can see I wrote a DBFactory func which is a factory pattern.

Comment: Passing a reference works. A `static` member variable would also work, but would take a bit of extra abstraction in order to scale to multiple runnable types operating on the same database.

Comment: Note: I'm just picking off the visible stuff. Without a [mre] there's no way to confirm that I've nailed the bug you're hunting.

Comment: Each thread has it's own `QSqlDatabase`. That's another problem

Comment: Why are you putting multiple things into `stockListQuery` with the same name?

Comment: @user4581301 I do want to deliver a reproducible example if this is not a question about database....

Comment: @MooingDuck I've updated the code and the result. And what do you mean "putting multiple things into stockListQuery with the same name", you mean the same "stock name" or the same "connection name".

Comment: You don't actually need the database. You can stub it out with a `std::cout << "sent XYZ to the database\n";` and focus on the thread syncronization.

Comment: After the updates, this question needs some serious cleaning... BTW, if you copied the code sample I provided, did what I suggested you to do and read the output, you would have encountered the errors you are having with your code and would know what to do to avoid them. Read the answer completely and carefully first, before you go to Google.

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach is to use a SQLite database like any other, including when multiple threads are involved. Let me explain.

In [[Using SQLite in multi-threaded applications](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)], one can read SQLite can be made thread safe:

- Section 1: Overview:
  *In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction.*
  In serialized mode, queries are executed 1 by 1.
- Section 2:
  Compile-time selection of threading mode: *Use the SQLITE_THREADSAFE compile-time parameter to select the threading mode. If no SQLITE_THREADSAFE compile-time parameter is present, then serialized mode is used.*

**The qsqlite driver shipped with Qt is compiled using the default mode, i.e. serialized.**
What it means for you is that you do not have to care ... almost.

---

The below sample demonstrates:

- What is IMHO the correct way to open connections to the same database from several threads:
  assuming you opened a connection from your main thread, use `QSqlDatabase::clone` when a worker thread starts (importantly: **inside the worker thread**), with the thread id in the connection name.
  If it makes it easier for you to retrieve, store the result of `clone` into a `thread_local QSqlDatabase database;` variable, declared in one of your `.cpp` files.
- Usage of the connection option `QSQLITE_BUSY_TIMEOUT`.
  This is the only thing that could make your queries fail **specifically** because you are using a multi-threaded environment.
- The rules as to how queries wait before being executed are similar, if not identical, to what [`std::shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex)/[`QReadWriteLock`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qreadwritelock.html) provide (I have not checked the code to see if it actually uses a `shared_mutex`): Read queries can be executed simultaneously.
  `QMutex` would hurt performance too much by making threads waiting for one another even when they do not have to.
  In the below sample:

  - If you shorten `QSQLITE_BUSY_TIMEOUT`, `t2` will fail (it times out before `t1` completes).
  - If you comment/remove the `query.finish();` (right before the actual test start) `t1` will fail.
    Explanation: Calling `finish()` (or destroying the `QSqlQuery`) is what releases the mutex; failng to do so + as `query` never goes out of scope, the mutex is kept by the main thread and outlives `t1`.
    Note that if `t2` may or may not fail as well, depending on when `t1` "gets out of the way".
  - If you keep the above `query.finish();` commented + you remove the body of the lambda inside `t1`, then `t2` will execute despite the main thread holding the mutex.

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDir>
#include <QtCore/QThread>
#include <QtCore/QVariant>

#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>
#include <QtSql/QSqlField>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QtSql/QSqlRecord>

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

thread_local QSqlDatabase database;

int main(int argc, char** arga)
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, arga);
    QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());

    QSqlDatabase mainDBConnection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "MainConnection");
    mainDBConnection.setDatabaseName("TestDatabase");
    //We want a long enough timeout for the test.
    mainDBConnection.setConnectOptions("QSQLITE_BUSY_TIMEOUT=30000");
    if (mainDBConnection.open()) {

        QSqlQuery query(mainDBConnection);
        query.exec("CREATE TABLE Test (ID INTEGER)");

        // Proceed with the test if above query is OK
        // or if the table was created during a previous test.
        if (auto error = query.lastError();
            error.type() == QSqlError::NoError || (
                error.type() == QSqlError::ErrorType::StatementError &&
                error.text() == "table Test already exists Unable to execute statement"
                )
            ) {
            query.exec("DELETE FROM Test");
            query.exec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test");
            query.finish(); //If you remove this line, the insertion done in t1 will not work.

            { //Start of the actual test.
                std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                // t1 executes a long-running INSERT query.
                std::thread t1([begin]() {
                    QString dbName = QString("t%1").arg(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(QThread::currentThreadId()));
                    database = QSqlDatabase::cloneDatabase("MainConnection", dbName);
                    database.open();
                    QSqlQuery query(database);
                    query.exec(
                        "WITH RECURSIVE r(i) AS (" \
                        "VALUES(0) " \
                        "UNION ALL " \
                        "SELECT 1+i FROM r " \
                        "LIMIT 10000000 " \
                        ") " \
                        "INSERT INTO Test SELECT i FROM r"
                    );
                    if (auto error = query.lastError();
                        error.type() != QSqlError::NoError
                        )
                        qDebug() << "Error in t1: " << error.text();
                    query.finish();
                    database.close();
                    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                    qDebug() << "t1 finished at: " <<
                        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << "ms";
                    });

                // t2 executes a SELECT query (after t1 has started).
                std::thread t2([begin]() {
                    // Wait to ensure t1 has started.
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                    QString dbName = QString("t%1").arg(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(QThread::currentThreadId()));
                    database = QSqlDatabase::cloneDatabase("MainConnection", dbName);
                    database.open();
                    QSqlQuery query(database);
                    query.exec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test");
                    if (query.first())
                        qDebug() << "Selected: " << query.record().field(0).value().toInt();
                    else
                        qDebug() << "Error in t2: " << query.lastError().text();
                    query.finish();
                    database.close();
                    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                    qDebug() << "t2 finished at: " <<
                        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << "ms";
                    });

                t1.join();
                t2.join();
            } //End of the actual test.
        }
        else
            qDebug() << "Test aborted because of error: " << error.type() << error.text();

        // Back to the main thread, we check the value returned by t2
        // counted all the records after t1 finished inserting.
        query.exec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test");
        if (query.first())
            qDebug() << "Expected result from t2: " << query.record().field(0).value().toInt();
        query.finish();
        mainDBConnection.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```